# How can I know the command used? - Discord.py

Tags: error-handling, discord, discord.py, embed

I am trying to make a errorhandling for my Discord.py, how do I know what command was used for the error to pop up?

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print("error: ",error)

    if search("not found", str(error)):
        c_f = random.choice([f"`{command used}` was not found, silly.", "Ehm.. Since when do we have `{command used}`?", "I don't know what `{command used}` is?"])
        embed=discord.Embed(title=c_f, description=f"Please use existing commands. {ctx.author.mention}", color=error_color)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
        embed.set_footer(text=bot_name, icon_url=icon_uri)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif search("cooldown", str(error)):
        c_d = random.choice(["Did you drink energy drinks!?", "Why are you stressing, buddy.", "Duhh, wait, you're on cooldown!"])
        second_remain = round(error.retry_after, 1)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=c_d, description=f"Try again after {second_remain}s. {ctx.author.mention}", color=error_color)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
        embed.set_footer(text=bot_name, icon_url=icon_uri)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        raise error
```

Any attribute I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ctx.command`

```py
    @bot.event
    async def on_command_error(ctx, exception):
        error = getattr(exception, "original", exception)

        if hasattr(ctx.command, "on_error"):  # If a command has it's own handler
            return

        elif isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
            return

        if isinstance(error, discord.CommandInvokeError):
            print(ctx.command)
```

Comment: I don't use cogs.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is to add them to the command specifically, this also means it can help diagnose an issue with a command more exact.

You can also add any error events to the specific listener, just like how you done it for all commands, instead add them individually.

```py
@bot.command()
async def command_name(ctx):
    # ...


@command_name.error 
async def command_name_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send("An error from this command" + error)
```

With `@command_name.error` put your command name before the .error, then this makes an error listener for that command, if it produces an error.

Comment: I don't really want to do that for all my commands, since I got plenty. I would like to just use an attribute the error has(if it does). Can't seem to find any in the docs.

Comment: You could just add these specific errors only to the commands that could throw an error

Comment: It's not a command, this error only occures when commands like `-dwadwa` is triggered. So I can make add it to specific commands, unless I want billions of lines.